# Capture varied requests with $httpBackend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to mock a backend for an app that I'm building using Angular JS.

I have the following code to mimic a successful request to log in:

```
// Login
$httpBackend.when('PUT','/v1/token/',{
    'domain'   : 'farmers',
    'username' : 'user',
    'password' : 'test'
}).respond({
    'token' : 'lalskdfjlskadjfklsadjf'
});
```

Of course this only works if I pass the exact object that I defined here.

I would like to know how I can change that to accept all `PUT` requests to `/v1/token/` regardless of the dataset passed. It should then check whatever data is passed to see if it matches the structure illustrated above, and then return either the token or a failure message.

**Is this possible?**

**Update:** So I'm trying to get this working.. I've put a function as the param of the `.respond()` function, to try to anticipate different possible datasets being passed.

**Javascript**

```
// Login
$httpBackend.when('PUT','/v1/token/').respond(function (method, url, data, headers) {
    var validLogin = {
        'domain'   : 'farmers',
        'username' : 'user',
        'password' : 'test'
    };

    if ( data !== validLogin ) {
        return {
            result : 'fail'
        };
    } else {
        return {
            'token' : 'lalskdfjlskadjfklsadjf'
        };
    }
});
```

This doesn't work at all though. Now no matter what I pass, I get an undefined error:

[image: undefined error in Chrome]

Comment: You mean requests of any verb (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE)?

Comment: @AndrewChurch No, sorry. I mean with any set of data. I'll update the question to be more precise

Comment: data will never equal validLogin. validLogin is an object, data is a string...

Comment: So if I changed `validLogin` to `"?domain=farmers&username=user&password=test"` it should work? Also if that's the case, shouldn't I be getting `{ 'result' : 'fail' }` in my console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your continuing problems stem from what you're returning from your `response` method. This worked for me:

```
$httpBackend.when('PUT','/v1/token/')
.respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
    var validLogin = {
      'domain'   : 'farmers',
      'username' : 'user',
      'password' : 'test'
    };

    if ( data !== JSON.stringify(validLogin)) {
        return [400, {failure: 'bad'}]
    } else {
        return [200, {token: '12345'}]
    } 
});
```

Notice how I'm returning an array of values (described in docs).

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vBAx6Ls28o8K31Zifolp?p=preview) (test passes whether token is returned or not - you need to look at console)

Comment: This should be put in the documentation to illustrate their point about the array better. I read the entire page but it didn't click for me

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for $httpBackend: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

You can use a function instead of an object to check the data, it will pass in a string. See below:

**EDIT** You need to put your "validData" matching logic in the data function, not the respond function...

```
// Login
$httpBackend.when('PUT','/v1/token/',function(dataString){
     var validLogin = {
        'domain'   : 'farmers',
        'username' : 'user',
        'password' : 'test'
     };

     var dataObject = JSON.parse(dataString);

     if (dataObject.username && dataObject.password && dataObject.domain) {
        return true;
     }
     else{
        return false;
     }
}).respond({
    'token' : 'lalskdfjlskadjfklsadjf'
});
```

Comment: Can the response be a function too? I want a different response depending on what the data is

Comment: requestHandler 
Returns an object with respond method that controls how a matched request is handled.

respond – {function([status,] data[, headers, statusText]) | function(function(method, url, data, headers)} – The respond method takes a set of static data to be returned or a function that can return an array containing response status (number), response data (string), response headers (Object), and the text for the status (string). - yes, you can use a function

Comment: I updated my question to show what happened when I try to use it. I've read the documentation, I find it very hard to follow

Comment: See my edit. You're data comparison needs to be in the data function so $httpBackend can determine if the request is a match BEFORE .respond is called.

Comment: @AndrewChurch I think they can get away with the comparison in the `respond`. Check out my answer.

Comment: This is closer to what I want but not quite. I need a definite response for both when the data is what I'm expecting or anything else. Also, this code isn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests that it takes in a regular expression, so you can do something like this:

```
$httpBackend.when('PUT', /\/v1\/token\/[1-9][0-9]*/)
```

Of course, this is just an example. Create your own regular expressions to match.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's not that I need to catch all different URLs, but that I catch all requests to the same URL regardless of the data passed

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, and the more in depth callback for respond to accomplish this. Here's an example of a fake API server:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/data.*/).respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
    var query = url.split('?')[1],
        requestParams = {};

    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        requestParams[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }

    for (var key in requestParams) {
        if (key.indexOf('[') >= 0) {
            var params = key.split(/\[(.*)\]/), value = requestParams[key], lastKey = '';

            angular.forEach(params.reverse(), function(name) {
                if (name != '') {
                    var v = value;
                    value = {};
                    value[lastKey = name] = isNumber(v) ? parseFloat(v) : v;
                }
            });
            requestParams[lastKey] =
                angular.extend(requestParams[lastKey] || {}, value[lastKey]);
        } else {
            requestParams[key] = 
                isNumber(requestParams[key]) ? parseFloat(requestParams[key]) : requestParams[key];
        }
    }

    var data = [ << a bunch of fake objects >> ];
    << do something to the data based on requestParams >>

    return [200, {
        result: data,
        total: data.length
    }];
});
$httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
```